# Gradle Experimental & Vector Drawable Support Library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-experimental, android-vectordrawable

I'm currently using Gradle Experimental 0.2.1, however I cannot use a more recent version.

I don't know if it's related but I need to use the new Vectore Support.

I tried adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to `defaultConfig.with` block but Gradle Sync will fail saying it does not recognize this feature.

The error I get is :

> Error:No such property: vectorDrawables for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor

This is my Gradle Build File :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "my.application.com
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true // this will fail
        }
    }

    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    // NDK
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "MyAwesomeJNILib"
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
        stl = 'gnustl_shared'    
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
            debuggable = true
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("demo") {
            applicationId = "my.application.com.demo"
        }

        create("dev") {
            applicationId = "my.application.com.dev"
        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

In the dependancies block I made sure to use

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'